# PHP Not Throwing Any Errors

Tags: php

Today I noticed that for some reason, my PHP dev environment is not displaying any errors, for syntax or otherwise.

Was working on a WordPress plugin (with debug on for WordPress), and tested it by putting in a file

Nothing. No errors, no warnings, nothing. I know the file is being called, because I manually went to that file. Still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and checking the `php.ini` settings for `display_errors`?

Comment: @tftd  Can you post as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check `php.ini` settings for `display_errors`

Answer (score 1):

As tftd pointed out, the display_errors php.ini option was set to off.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer so people who find this question in the future see it quickly?

Comment: You can't accept your own answer for 48 hours after posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

use `echo error_reporting();` in php code of your dev env and compare it to `error_reporting settings` in `phpinfo()` (also in php dev env).

If equal, then check php.ini as it was told above.